Formatting hovertext of two variable bar plot
I have the following dataset,
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(lubridate)
library(reshape2)

year <- c(2000:2004)
variable1 <- c(10, 14, 23, 14, 20)
variable2 <- c(9, 19, 28, 16, 18)

dtf <- data.frame(year, variable1, variable2)
dtf$year <- lubridate::parse_date_time(dtf$year, orders = "%Y")
dtf$year <- as.Date(dtf$year)
p1 <- melt(dtf, id.vars = "year") |> 
  mutate(across("variable", str_replace, "variable1", "Variable 1")) |> 
  mutate(across("variable", str_replace, "variable2", "Variable 2"))

I have plot that works except the hovertemplate part.
plot_ly(p1, 
       x = ~year, 
       y = ~value, 
       type="bar",
       color=~variable,
       hovertext = ~paste0(year, "<br>", variable, "<br>", value),
       hoverinfo = "text"#,
       #hovertemplate = paste("%Y", "%{y:.2f}", ""))
       )

I want to have my hovertext like this,
Year: 2000
Variable 1
value (2 decimal points)

The middle line works if I set the #hovertemplate = paste("%Y", "%{y:.2f}", ""). But not the other two. Any idea how to achieve my expectation?

Here is an option to achieve your desired result using the hovertemplate= attribute:
library(plotly)

plot_ly(p1,
  x = ~year,
  y = ~value,
  type = "bar",
  color = ~variable,
  text = ~variable,
  hovertemplate = paste("Year: %{x|%Y}", "%{text}", "%{y:.2f}", sep = "<br>")
)


Or using hovertext= and hoverinfo= you could do:
plot_ly(p1,
  x = ~year,
  y = ~value,
  type = "bar",
  color = ~variable,
  hovertext = ~ paste0(
    "Year: ", format(year, "%Y"), "<br>",
    variable, "<br>",
    sprintf("%.2f", value)
  ),
  hoverinfo = "text"
)


Thanks. The 2nd option works. The hovertemplate option shows the %{text}, not Variable 1 or Variable 2.
However, even hovertext + hoverinfo way works, config(locale="de") is not changing the config to delocale. Forhovertemplate` way, the locale config works.

Concerning the issue with hovertemplate=: Have you added text = ~variable? And yes. From my understanding: When you use hovertext + hoverinfo or text= then the hovertext is added as a string, i.e. you have to do all the formatting your self. In contrast, for hovertemplate the formatting is done on the fly and hence can account for locale specific formatting.

Thanks for the hint. It works now! One last question: how to get rid of the Variable 1 outside of the box?

Try with hovertemplate = paste0(paste("Year: %{x|%Y}", "%{text}", "%{y:.2f}", sep = "<br>"), "<extra></extra>"). The "" part will remove the series name.
